# Предопределённые идентификаторы FASM, NASM

Tags: ассемблер, fasm

Если я хочу определить, например, текущую разрядность кода в MASM32 или TASM, я могу написать `if @WordSize eq 4` или `if @32Bit` (в TASM).

А можно ли сделать такую проверку в **FASM**, **NASM** (YASM) ? Какие вообще предопределённые символы есть в FASM и NASM (YASM) ?

Comment: Кто или что мешает вам посмотреть в документацию к нужному ассемблеру?

Comment: @PinkTux, я уже читал. Ничего нет. Единственный вариант, который приходит в голову для FASM - это сделать вот так: http://i7.5cm.ru/i/fEjC.png ... но, может, есть вариант проще?

Comment: Конечную цель озвучьте. Если это нечто вроде сишных `#ifdef` для написания кода под разные архитектуры/разрядность - лучше сразу выкинуть эту идею из головы. Даже для поделок уровня "одна палка, два струна" этот подход себя не оправдывает.

Comment: @PinkTux, почему это?

Comment: Попробуйте - узнаете. В конечном итоге в эти ифдефы будет обёрнуто 99% кода. Не говоря уж о том, что для разных архитектур код может будет разный алгоритмически. А главное - зачем? Программы на ассемблере всегда имеют очень узкую цель. Написав на нём сотни тысяч строк под разные архитектуры не могу вспомнить чтобы пришлось писать одновременно под разные.

Comment: @PinkTux, в достаточно многих случаях всё достаточно просто. Во-первых, что касается регистров ax/eax, bx/ebx и т.д, то можно определить идентификаторы $ax, $bx и т.д., например, которые будут эквивалентны ax, bx или eax, ebx в зависимости от разрядности и использовать именно их. С адресацией памяти сложнее, конечно. А нужно это может быть, например, при написании include-файла с каким-либо функциями, который должен работать и на 16 и на 32 битах.

Comment: @PinkTux, если этот вариант не нравится, можно сделать include-файл, который будет содержать что-то вроде if Bit32 \ include funcs32.inc \ include more32.inc \ include other32.inc \ else \ include funcs16.inc \ include more16.inc \ include other16.inc \ endif ну и т.д.

Comment: Так вам нужны просто макросы для типичных действий типа "вывести строку на экран"? Тоже баловался подобным. Но недолго, выкинул по причинам, изложеным выше.

Comment: @PinkTux, не макросы, а функции только :)

Comment: Тем более. Функции пишутся под конкретную архитектуру. А то и по конкретный ассемблер, и под конкретный рантайм. Но через какое-то время придёт понимание, что 80% этих функций, если не больше, и так есть в `libc`, и их использование может быть эффективней велосипедостроительства. А функции, специфичные для проекта, пишутся под проект, который, в свою очередь, завязан на (см сначала). Впрочем, время - ваше, и как его убивать решать вам.

Answer (score 0):

Для fasm нет предопределенных констант (по крайней мере в документации никаких упоминаний нет).

Чтобы создавать разный код для с разной разрядностью, можно создать несколько "корневых" asm файлов, в которых можно задать нужные константы и, например, переопределения регистров в зависимости от разрядности.

Подобным образом реализована компиляция самого flat assembler для разных систем: в директории SOURCE есть несколько поддиректорий (DOS, WIN32, LIBC и LINUX (+ директория X64 внутри)), в которых лежат файлы fasm.asm, которые компилируются каждый в свой формат (mz, pe, elf (.o), elf, elf64) с учетом специфики каждой из систем, но ссылаются на общие inc-файлы из родительской директории. Платформозависимый код занимает в общей сложности порядка 100 КБ, общие файлы - порядка 650 КБ (для версии fasm 1.71.64 (Jul 18, 2017)).